# Understand Laravel route with optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm trying to create a route with one optional parameter with Laravel 5.4.

Route :

```
Route::get('/run/{zone?}/id/{id}', 'RunController@show');
```

Controller :

```
class RunController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $route = \Route::current();
        $zone = $route->parameter('zone') ?: 'default';
        $id = $route->parameter('id');

        Run::setZone($zone);
        $run = Run::findOrFail($id);
        return view('run.show')->with(['run' => $run]);
    }
}
```

The url `run/test/id/42` works like expected.

But with `run/id/42` I got a nice `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php` when I expect the same result than `run/default/id/42`

What did I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after the first optional parameter must be optional. If part of the route after an optional parameter is required, then that parameter becomes required.

In your case, the `id/{id}` part of the route is non-optional, so the "optional" parameter before that section of the route becomes required.

Laravel's routing is actually built on top of Symfony's routing, and this is a restriction in Symfony. According to the [Symfony documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/optional_placeholders.html) (emphasis mine):

> Of course, you can have more than one optional placeholder (e.g. `/blog/{slug}/{page}`), **but everything after an optional placeholder must be optional**. For example, `/{page}/blog` is a valid path, but page will always be required (i.e. simply `/blog` will not match this route).

Additionally, another thing to watch out for:

> Routes with optional parameters at the end will not match on requests with a trailing slash (i.e. `/blog/` will not match, `/blog` will match).

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters work when it is the last URL element so in your case it won't work.

Comment: You are probably right, but I don't find anything about this in the documentation.