# Laravel 5 advanced routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

everyone. I can't 2 link urls with to 2 different controllers :(

```
Route::group([
    'namespace'  => 'Page',
    'as'         => 'page.',
], function() use ($lang)
{
    Route::get ('/{path}-{page_id}',                  ['uses' => 'PageCategoryController@show',       'as' => 'category']);
    Route::get ('/{path?}/{alias}-{record_id}.html',  ['uses' => 'PageItemController@show',           'as' => 'item']);
});
```

When you are going to url

```
/test-3
/test-3.html
```

you have the same result, but why?

```
uri GET {path}-{page_id}
as  frontend::page.category
```

Please, help me :)

---

UPDATED:

Maybe it because of this, but I'm not sure...

```
Route::pattern('path',      '[-_a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]*');
Route::pattern('alias',     '[-_a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]*');
Route::pattern('record_id', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('page_id',   '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: This question is quite confusing...

Comment: @VolodymyrAndryeyev : Laravel routing confused by option param `{path?}` and if true for both url. you need to make sure about each identification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to [Understand Laravel route with optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666683/understand-laravel-route-with-optional-parameter)

You can't have an optional parameter followed by a required parameter.

However, maybe this workaround may work for you

```
Route::get ('/{alias}-{record_id}.html', ['uses' => 'PageItemController@show', 'as' => 'item']);
Route::get ('/{path}/{alias}-{record_id}.html', ['uses' => 'PageItemController@show', 'as' => 'item']);
Route::get ('/{path}-{page_id}', ['uses' => 'PageCategoryController@show', 'as' => 'category']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the second one before the first one:

```
Route::get ('/{path?}/{alias}-{record_id}.html', ['uses' => 'PageItemController@show', 'as' => 'item']);
Route::get ('/{path}-{page_id}', ['uses' => 'PageCategoryController@show', 'as' => 'category']);
```

Comment: @ВолодимирАндрєєв if `PageCategoryController@show` is still executed, try to clear the cache with `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @VolodymyrAndryeyev : Laravel routing confused by option param `{path?}` and if true for both url. you need to make sure about each identification

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin : as you suggested, It would always take first route now

Comment: @VolodymyrAndryeyev I've tested this and I can't find any way to make it work except adding the third route and modifying the second one like fab shows in this answer.